# Trying to find with euclidean distance the closest ones

Tags: python-3.x, euclidean-distance

```
import imagehash
from PIL import Image
import glob
import numpy as np
import csv
from scipy.spatial import distance

image_list = []
list_rows = []

for filename in glob.glob('/home/folder1/*.jpg'):
    im = Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
    img_hash = imagehash.average_hash(im)
    print(img_hash)
    list_rows.append([img_hash])

np.savetxt("numpy_test.csv", list_rows, delimiter=",", fmt='% s')

with open('numpy_test.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

print(data)

for hashes in data:
    print(hashes)

mouni = []
mouni_rows = []
for file in glob.glob('/home/folder2/test.jpg'):
    img = Image.open(file)
    mouni.append(img)
    img_hash = imagehash.average_hash(img)
    print(img_hash)
    mouni_rows.append([img_hash])

np.savetxt("numpy_test_mouni.csv", mouni_rows, delimiter=",", fmt='% s')

with open('numpy_test_mouni.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    mouni = list(reader)

print(mouni)

for k in mouni:
    print(k)

for i in hashes:
    for y in k:
        dist = np.linalg.norm(i - y)
        print(dist)
```

-Folder1 contains some images from which imagehashes are extracetd and saved to a .csv file

-Folder2 contains only 1 image and imagehash is extracted and saved to an other .csv file

-The goal is to compare the imagehash from the 1 image with the rest of the hashes using the euclidean distance in order to find the closest ones. But the error is: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Any advice really appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: Your CSV files contains string data. Since you didn't show the files we can't know whether these strings might represent numbers but your code certainly doesn't convert anything. Hence, you are trying to compute the (numerical) difference between to strings which doesn't work, as the error says.

Comment: The first file contains the hashes extracted from the images like these: ffffffffbfbfbfff
ffffff7f7fffffff
bf9fc7e3f1fdffff and the other file contains only one hash ffffff7f7fffffff